# Addition returns wrong value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When I tried with additions of variables I saw that:

https://jsfiddle.net/tyfyLsw9/

I think it's because this doesn't contain an integer.

```
  var month = $("#monthd").val();
  var J = 1;
  var D = 8;
  var K = J + D;
  var U = J + month;
```

As you can see in fiddle J + month returns 110 instead of 11, why?

Comment: `.val()` returns a string. Convert to a number with `var month = Number($("#monthd").val());` or with the unary plus operator: `var month = +$("#monthd").val();`.

Comment: @nnnnnn So how can I retrieve the value in an integer ?

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @Vohuman Hi don't know ;(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: Yep thanks @Juhana

Comment: @ShotNet, I edited your question as per my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a string, so the number you are adding gets coerced into a string as well. `"10" + "1" = "101"`;

simply wrap the value returned in a `Number` Construct

```
var month = Number($("#monthd").val());
```

additionally you can use parseInt if the values are integers.

```
var month = parseInt($("#monthd").val(), 10);
```

the `, 10` is important to parse it with base 10.